# Merge tags: coronavirus and covid19

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonyms

We now have both a [coronavirus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coronavirus) and a [covid19](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid19) tag. Since all the coronavirus questions are about COVID-19, these should be merged or made synonyms.

I do not think the covid19 tag should be destroyed since it is very likely that someone else will just recreate it with a new question.

Comment: "I do not think the covid19 tag should be destroyed since it is very likely that someone else will just recreate it with a new question." Blacklisting is an option.

Comment: @Mast If we opt to make all COVID-19 questions just be tagged health instead as suggested by Dark Cygnus a blacklist of both terms should be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[coronavirus](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coronavirus) and [covid19](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid19) have both been merged into [covid-19](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) and synonyms created. A single-sentence tag wiki has been added but it could use additional detail.

Answer (score 4):

I want to remind everybody that **we already have a [health](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) tag**, that applies perfectly to this situation (one's physical health in the workplace).

Personally, **I would advice on considering using the [health](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) tag instead, if the case is fit** (where the answers could be applied to health in general).

Besides, I advice to **be aware of posts where the covid-19 tag was included, but the question and core issue are something completely unrelated to health or covid**. Or where other more relevant tags were left out.

For example (out of my mind), cases like: *Communicating something to a colleague or boss via email, in the Uk, because X thing happened... because Y thing happened on project Z... because covid...*

We can see that here the core tag should be [communication](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication), and other related tags would be *colleague*, *management*, *software-development* perhaps, *email* perhaps also, and so forth... The answers that post would get would surely be useful and work regardless of the Covid situation; some other reader that also needs to send that email would find the answers useful in a future even though Covid is no longer around. **Cases like these is where the [covid-19](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) should not be (ab)used**.

Now, in any other case where Covid is intrinsic to the issue or question (and is NOT asking for medical or legal advise) the tag applies.

Comment: As you said health deals with `one's physical health`  I think that covid-19 deals more with societal issues (social distancing/ remote working, etc) than just a health tag would. covid-19 would be more on the lines of the whole company adjusting, while health would be them adjusting for you.

Comment: I suggest making a distinction between general workplace health questions that will go on being useful for years, and questions specific to the current pandemic that will be very important for a few months.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan exactly. That's why we must be aware of the correct use of health versus covid-19, and fix the posts that require so.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan updated my answer to better reflect what I am trying to say.